# Adjusting the User control to Stackpanel's size

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and I have come across a small issue. I have an UserControl which contains a Stackpanel. Inside the stackpanel there are multiple richtxtboxes and it will be visible or collapsed as per the condition at runtime. The problem is, that the user control remains the same size ( i would want it to be the size of stackpanel at runtime). I have set Height and width property to the usercontrol with some values. I have searched about it and got suggestions to remove the height and width property. But that makes the whole wpf panel to collapse. Can anyone help, pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting const sizes isn`t good - only if needed. Anyway here is your solution

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Width="{Binding ElementName=MyStackPanel, Path=ActualWidth}"
             Height="{Binding ElementName=MyStackPanel, Path=ActualHeight}">

    <Grid>

        <StackPanel Width="350" 
                    Height="350" 
                    x:Name="MyStackPanel" 
                    Background="Blue" />

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its Perfect :) Have a nice day!